# Unable to access AWS EC2 instance after replacing root volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I was trying to migrate AWS EC2 c5 to c6g.

Everything was going fine but when I replaced the root volume of c6g (new instance) by attaching the root volume of the previous c5 instance, I could not access the instance via ssh. All I see is a message saying **"Unable to connect to your instance..."**

**SSH response:**

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/mekapilbasnet/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 3.7.103.6 [3.7.103.6] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 3.7.103.6 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 3.7.103.6 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Using SSH? Did you try with -v option for more info?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.
I have updated the question with the SSH response.

Comment: Timeout usually suggest network issues. Could be caused by security groups or some firewall running on the instance.

Comment: I have used the same security group that I have been using from the very beginning.

Comment: What about web ssh clients? AWS provides two of them, which you can access from EC2 aws console.

Comment: Tried but failed:
https://i.imgur.com/Hdxifrs.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248529/discussion-between-kapil-basnet-and-marcin).

Comment: No valid answers have been received yet. Waiting for the one.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I delete known_hosts file from .ssh/ directory, and recreated it using `ssh -i "pem_key.pem" user@ip_address`